# How to set the data-attribute of a button to whatever value set in an input [type=text]?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-modal, custom-data-attribute

I have a modal and inside my modal is an input[type]. And I want to set default value and that default value is from a data-attribute of a button..

Here is my code:

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ID" id="ID" placeholder="Enter ID number"/>
                <button id="confirmation" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm">Submit</button>
```

and this:

```
document.getElementById("ID").onmouseover = function() {
    var id=document.getElementById("ID").value;

    $('#confirmation').attr('data-id' , id); 

    return false;
};

$('#confirm').on('show.bs.modal', function (event)  {
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
    var id = button.data('id') // Extract info from data-* attributes
    var modal = $(this)
    modal.find('.modal-body #IDN').val(id);
});
```

I can set the data-attribute of the `button` but the problem is if I change the value in the input textfield. The data-attribute doesn't change. How am I going to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `blur`

```
$('#ID').blur(function() {
  $('#confirmation').data('id', this.value);

});
```

Answer (score 3):

Use jQuery [**`change()`**](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event handler

```js
$('#ID').change(function() {
  $('#confirmation').data('id', this.value);
  console.log($('#confirmation').data('id'));
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="ID" id="ID" placeholder="Enter ID number" />
<button id="confirmation" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm">Submit</button>
```

or use [**`keypress()`**](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/) event

```js
$('#ID').keypress(function() {
  $('#confirmation').data('id', this.value);
  console.log($('#confirmation').data('id'));
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="ID" id="ID" placeholder="Enter ID number" />
<button id="confirmation" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm">Submit</button>
```

Comment: This actually works but it doesn't change the data-id value to the current inputted value.. it sets the data-id to the previous value inputted in the textfield.. :(

Comment: If you want to update on each keypress then use second method

Comment: Thanks for your time and answer :) I used blur instead because I when tried on keypress, the last inputted character is not included..